# Get Value from another file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get **Values** from another workbook based on **No.Id** and insert a new column between columns.

For example, I have data like this:
1st workbook is on the left and 2nd Workbook on the right is.
[image]

On 2nd Workbook I want to insert a new column between column and put the values based on **No.Id** after click on **CommandButton1**.

So the 2nd Workbook looks like this after macro
[image]

Comment: Tackle the problems one by one. Learn how to open another workbook, how to insert columns etc. Then, if you have a problem with one of these tasks, ask for help with that specific problem.

Comment: If the basic command like insert column and open another workbook I can do it, but my only concern is get value from another workbook and making the values same as No.Id just like the picture. I mean it's really frustating me :( . By the way thanks for the advice.. :)

Comment: That would be one of the tasks, to copy value from another workbook. If you can open the other workbook it should be no problem as you only need to read and write cell values?

Comment: No, the issue is not just copy and paste values from one workbook to another. The real question is how can I copy the **Values** based on **No.Id** so it can match from the 1st Workbook. For the example If I have **No.Id** **4** on 2nd Workbook and after I put CommandButton1 and click it the Values column fill with **D** . Any sugestion ? Because it's really frustating me :(

Comment: So are you asking how to find a certain value in a column?

Comment: Yeah exactly, do you have any sugestion ?

Comment: Yes as I suggested in my very first comment. [like so](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+find+value+in+column)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("NAME SOURCE SHEET")
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Set wsOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("NAME OUTPUT SHEET")
Dim ID as Range
Dim FindID as Range
Dim lRowSource as Integer
Dim lRowOutput as Integer

lRowSource = wsSource.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
lRowOutput = wsSource.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

With wsOutput
    Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert

    For each ID in .Range("A1:A" & lRowSource)
    Set FindID = wsSource.Range("A1:A" & lRowOutput).Find(What:=ID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not FindID is Nothing then
        wsSource.Range("B" & FindID.Row).Copy Destination:=wsOutput.Range("B" & FindID.Row)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
```

Or you can also use:

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("NAME SOURCE SHEET")
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Set wsOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("NAME OUTPUT SHEET")
Dim i As Long

wsOutput.Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert

For i=1 To wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If wsSource.Range("A" & i) = wsOutput.Range("A" & i) Then
        wsSource.Range("B" & i).Copy Destination:=wsOutput.Range("B" & i)
    End If
Next i
```